# MIPS- beq not branching to the proper function?

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

I'm very new to writing code in MIPS, so any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to a simple mips program, but my program seems to keep going to the else statement everytime.

```
        .text
        .globl __start
__start:                 # execution starts here

printprompt:
        la $a0,prompt0   # print prompt on terminal
        li $v0,4         # system call to print
        syscall          # out a string
    
        #reading user input
    la $a0, str1
    li $a1, 80
        li $v0, 8
        syscall

    
    #   la $a0,str1     # checking $a0 print on terminal
    #   li $v0,4        # system call to print
    #   syscall         # out a string
        
    
    lb $a0, ($a0)   #added code here- it's working now
    
    #if 'c' or 'C' branch to convertC2F 
    beq $a0 , 'c', convertC2F
    beq $a0 , 'C', convertC2F

        #if 'f' or 'F' branch to convertf2C
    beq $a0 , 'f' , convertf2C
    beq $a0, 'F'  , convertf2C

        #else go to error       
    j error
        
        

    
    


        
convertC2F:
        
        la $a0,prompt   # print prompt on terminal
        li $v0,4        # system call to print
        syscall         # out a string
        li $v0,5        # syscall 5 reads an integer
        syscall         
    mul $t0,$v0,9       # to convert, multiply by 9,
    div $t0,$t0,5       # divide by 5, then
    addi $t0,$t0,32     # add 32

    la $a0,ans1         # print string before result
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    move $a0,$t0        # print result
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0,endl # syscal to print out
    li $v0,4    # a new line
    syscall 


    
    li $v0,10
    syscall     # Bye!
    
    
convertf2C:

        la $a0,prompt   # print prompt on terminal
        li $v0,4        # system call to print
        syscall         # out a string

        li $v0,5        # syscall 5 reads an integer
        syscall         

    addi $t0,$v0,-32    # to convert, subtract input by 32
    mul $t0, $t0, 5     # multiply by 9
    div $t0,$t0,9       # divide by 9, then


    la $a0,ans1         # print string before result
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    move $a0,$t0        # print result
    li $v0,1
    syscall
    
    
    li $v0,10
    syscall     # Bye!
    
    
error:
    la $a0, prompt3
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    
    la $a0,endl # syscal to print out
    li $v0,4    # a new line
    syscall 
    
    j printprompt


    
    li $v0,10
    syscall     # Bye!
    
    
    
#################################################
#                                               #
#               data segment                    #
#                                               #
#################################################

        .data
        prompt0: .asciiz "Enter c, C or f F: "
        
        str1:   .space 80
        prompt: .asciiz "Enter temperature: "
    
        prompt3:    .asciiz "Wrong letter: "
        ans1:   .asciiz "The temperature is "
        endl:   .asciiz "\n"
```

I tried rearranging the order to see if that makes any difference, but for any input c,C,f, and F it all keeps going to the error function and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: That's because `$a0` is a pointer to your `str1` where the input is stored. You need to load it first e.g. you could do `lb $a0, ($a0)` as a quick fix.

Comment: When I add that, it prints (null) and shows up as memory address out of bounds

Comment: Why not update your code in the question post to show where you added that line.

Comment: My bad, it's working. Thankyou both of you. I was inserting it in the wrong place, I have updated the code

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need to compare both capital and lower case letters like that back to back. You can do `lb $a0,($a0) ori $a0,0x20 beq $a0, 'c' convertC2F beq $a0,'f', convertC2F` and it's the same outcome. This is because going from capital to lower case is the same as doing a bitwise OR with 32.